# Android Studio - Problema con compose image

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, jetpack-compose

Estoy intentando que me muestre un icono que esta en la carpeta `/res/drawable` con `compose`.

El texto si me lo pinta en el preview, pero la imagen me esta todo el rato saltando error en drawable.

He probado multitud de cosas pero no consigo hacerlo funcionar, alguien sabe que puede ser?.

```
Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.*drawable*.ic_launcher_background),
            contentDescription = null // decorative element
        )
```

Comment: Por favor, añade el código de error que te genera.

Comment: Un error de sintaxis? Esos asteríscos (`*`) están sobrando.

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el error que te sale en el `logcat`?  Como dijo @SinneroftheSystem los asteríscos están demás